# From where i can find the full official documentation about the SharePoint REST API end point for creating sharing links

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, external-users, sharing

Inside any SharePoint Online sites, we have the following four sharing options: -

[image: User's image]

Now I am building a custom REST API (one using Power Automate, the other using .NET Core)>> which should generate the above four sharing options. So, from where I can find a full documentation from Microsoft about the related rest service api endpoint and the available options? mainly I want the following scenarios: -

- Create/Generate "Anyone" link with password + View permission
- Create/Generate "People you choose" + View permission + specifying the list of emails (internal & external) + Without sending direct invitation email (only generating the link).

can anyone advice on this please? from where I can find the related documentations from Microsoft which details how to implement the above scenarios using SharePoint REST API ?

Comment: I don't think there will be any detailed Microsoft official SharePoint REST API documentation for this scenarios. SharePoint REST API documentation is not detailed (they don't have documentation for every endpoint) and properly managed by Microsoft - personal thought.

Comment: @GaneshSanap so what we can do to understand those APIs ? can we use the browser developer tool to inspect the API details ? and if we do so , can we be sure that those parameters will not get changed in the future ? since we do not have any official docs for it ?

Comment: Yes, you can use browser developer tool and Network tab to inspect the API details Or check if you can open support ticket with Microsoft directly and get those details from them. Most probably those parameters will not be changed, but we never know for sure if anything will be changed by Microsoft or not.

Comment: If your googling didn't find it then the APIs are probably undocumented and unsupported. You can reverse engineer them, but you'll be on the hook for figuring it out and supporting it when MS changes it and breaks your solution.

Comment: @DerekGusoff thanks for the reply.. i used the browser developer tool to inspect the Shrelink parameters. where for example sending "role:1" will grant the sharing link "View permission",, so could this get changed in the future and sending "role:1" will result in granting the sharing link "Edit" beside "View"? also inside this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharing.role?view=sharepoint-csom MS mentioned that 1 means View. but at the same time, it added this message on the top of the page

Comment: @DerekGusoff .`."Some information relates to prerelease product that may be substantially modified before it’s released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here." `.. so what do you think ?